# Jenkins with Kubernetes Client Plugin - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

After upgrading the jenkins plugin Kubernetes Client to version 1.30.3 (also for 1.31.1) I get the following exceptions in the logs of jenkins when I start a build:

```
Timer task org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesClientProvider$UpdateConnectionCount@2c16d367 failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'okhttp3.OkHttpClient io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.HttpClientAware.getHttpClient()'
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesClientProvider$UpdateConnectionCount.doRun(KubernetesClientProvider.java:150)
    at hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.run(SafeTimerTask.java:90)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

After some of these eceptions the build itself is cancelled with this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for websocket connection. You should increase the value of system property org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator.websocketConnectionTimeout currently set at 30 seconds
at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.doLaunch(ContainerExecDecorator.java:451)
at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.launch(ContainerExecDecorator.java:338)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:507)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:176)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:132)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:324)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:319)
```

Do you have an idea what can be done?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Downgrade the plugin to kubernetes-client-api:5.10.1-171.vaa0774fb8c20. The latest one has the compatibility issue as of now.

**new info**: The issue is now solved with upgrading the **Kubernetes plugin** to version: 1.31.2 https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-67483

Comment: Thank you. I was dealing with the same problem. This information saved the night.

Comment: Relevant [Jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-67484)

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Fyi, if you're like me and need a fresh install using helm - this worked for me: helm install jenkins jenkins/jenkins --version 3.10.2 --set 'controller.installPlugins={kubernetes:1.31.1,workflow-aggregator:2.6,git:4.10.1,configuration-as-code:1.55,kubernetes-client-api:5.10.1-171.vaa0774fb8c20}' -n jenkins

Comment: Life saver !! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by upgrading the Jenkins image to `jenkins/jenkins-2.328-centos7-jdk8` and updating the Kubernetes plugin to `1.31.2`